# case class 22 parameters issue with Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala

I am in situation where I have to use scala 2.10 (since I have spark running on 2.10) 
I am using json4s along but for jsons those have more than 22 parameters. Case class breaks.

Is there any alternative way to handle this?

Comment: Must you use a case class? What else are you doing with that class? Pattern matching? Are you using it as a key in a `Map`?

Comment: I should be fine with other class if not case class.

Comment: Use a `class` instead of `case class` then.

Comment: Perhaps you could group some of the parameters together and put them inside a new class?

Comment: This might be interesting for you: Serialize shapeless HList-based records to json with json4s and Scala (https://github.com/rrmckinley/jsonless).

Comment: thanks, the other way would be to create normal class instead of case class. I am trying to figure out, how that be done.