# Using Play Framework and case class with greater than 22 parameters

Tags: json, scala, playframework, case-class

I have seen some of the other issues involving the infamous "22 fields/parameters" issue that is an inherent bug (feature?) of Scala V < 2.11. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152772/case-class-22-parameters-issue-with-scala-2-10) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494526/how-to-unlimit-spray-jsonformat). However, as per this [blog post](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html), it appears that the 22 parameter limit in `case class` has been fixed; at least where the language is concerned.

I have a `case class` that I want to load an arbitrary (Read: > 22) number of values into which will later be read into a JSON object using the Play library.

It looks something like this:

```scala
object L {
  import play.api.libs.json.Reads. _
  import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

  implicit val responseRead: Reads[L] = (
    MyField1.jsPath.Read[MyField1.t] and 
    MyField2.jsPath.Read[MyField2.t] and
    ...
    MyField35.jsPath.Read[MyField35.t]
  ) (L.apply _)
}

case class L(myField1: MyField1.t, myField2: MyField2.t, ... myField35: MyField35.t)
```

The issue is that on compile, Scala complains that there are more than 22 parameters in the `case class`. (Specifically: on the last line of the object definition, when the compiler attempts to build, I get: "implementation restricts functions to 22 parameters".) I'm currently using Scala v2.11.6, so I **think** it's not a language issue. That makes me think that the Play library hasn't updated their implementation of `Read`.

If that's the case, then I guess the best bet is to group related fields into Tuples and pass the Tuples in through the JSON API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question is actually two parts:

#### 1. Workaround

I'll call this the "workaround" because while it does "work" it usually addresses the symptom and not the problem.

My solution was to use `shapeless` to provide generic heterogeneous lists of arbitrary length. This solution is already widely discussed and available elsewhere. See, e.g., (1) [SO Post] [How to get around the Scala case class limit of 22 fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258417/how-to-get-around-the-scala-case-class-limit-of-22-fields); (2)  [Blog post](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html); (3) [Yet another blog post](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/08/08/slickless.html).

#### 2. Solution

As @jeffrey-chung mentions is to restructure the model to deal with this limit. As many in the industry have noted, having a function with more than 30 arguments is likely a sign that your function is doing too much or that the function should be refactored to ingest a smaller number of arguments. See, e.g., (1) [Rule of 30 – When is a method, class or subsystem too big?](http://swreflections.blogspot.com/2012/12/rule-of-30-when-is-method-class-or.html); (2) [Databrick's style guide](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#rule_of_30).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the blog post you referenced, the 22-parameter limit is still in effect for functions in Scala 2.11 and later, so what you've encountered *is* a language issue. The function call in this case is:

```
L.apply _
```

Restructuring your model is one way to deal with this limit.

Comment: Restructuring the model however can't always be done. See the workaround, below.

Answer (score 0):

See answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317220/1606452

It seems this handles it all nicely.

**+22 field case class formatter and more for play-json**
https://github.com/xdotai/play-json-extensions

Supports Scala 2.11.x, 2.12.x, and 2.13.x and play 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 and 2.7

And is referenced in the [play-json issue](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/issues/3) as the preferred solution (but not yet merged)