# Playframework: Too many argument for mapping method in form

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, slick

I'm using Slick to connect to the database. But, in my table has over 22 fields. I'm so confused in using form. Compiler notifying me that too many argument for mapping method. I found some ways to solve it, such as using nested values, but they are not detail. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using nested classes (with less than 22 fields for convenience).

### Data model

```
case class Address(city: String)

case class Person(firstName: String, address: Address)
```

### Nested forms

```
val personForm = Form[Person](
    "firstName" -> text,
    "address" -> mapping(
        "city" -> text
    )(Address.apply)(Address.unapply)
)(Person.apply)(Person.unapply)
```

### Slick nested (using one table only)

```
class PersonTableDef(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "person") {
    def name = column[String]("name")

    def city = column[String]("city")

    def address = (city) <> ((Address.apply _).tupled, Address.unapply)

    def * = (name, address) <> ((Person.apply _).tupled, Person.unapply)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So, how to  use form in views and controller ? I'm confused in using it.

Comment: Have you read that : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms ?

Comment: But I dont know how to use nested form as you show me above and get data from it. I can use personForm("name") and get data in controller by using data.name, but I dont know how to do with "city".

Comment: Not sure but, have you tried `personForm("address")("city")` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. How to get "city" in controller?

Comment: Well, you can use something like this `form.bindFromRequest.fold(..., person => person.address.city ...)`. You actually get the person object here

Comment: But compiler notify that city is not a member of Address

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can separate into several tables and build a composite object as if it were an inheritance. Well, you could not convert the entity to json either...

Help links similars but with another approach:

[In stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551414/using-play-framework-and-case-class-with-greater-than-22-parameters)

[External docs by Underscore](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/10/11/twenty-two.html)